# Any mechanism to copy only required u-boot source code to a folder?

Tags: linux, makefile, u-boot, kbuild

I'm going through the u-boot source code and it has many arch and vendor's code.
Also it has the source code with pre-processor directive as "#ifdef" etc.

I want to filter/extract the code based on my u-boot configuration.
There should be some way to tell the compiler so it can copy only the source code (to a new folder) which will be the part of my executable.

If it's possible then it will be easy to go through the source code and understand the code flow.

Is there any tool or compiler option available for this?

Thanks,
Hardik

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are off-topic here. And as I understand the question, some aspects of what you are after are outside the scope of what a compiler can do.  Many compilers do have an option to output preprocessed source code (the `-E` option to `gcc`, for example), but I think you'll find that that's not really what you want.

Comment: Could you please suggest that which forum should I look for the help?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into the Yocto WORKDIR so it's having only required files
in this directory so now it would be easy to go through the code.

These are object files but based on file names I can refer the c files.